# Javascript add and delete class on a button on click

Tags: javascript, class, if-statement, button

I'm trying to create a button click event. I usually use a value to check whether the button is already clicked, but some buttons have a different kind of value:

```
if (quizUrl.indexOf(tgt.value) === -1) {
   if (tgt.value === 'Negeren') {
       el.ClearArray(quizUrl)
       if (tgt.classList.contains('activeMulti')){
           tgt.classList.remove('activeMulti');
       } else {
           tgt.classList.add('activeMulti');
       }
   } else {
       quizUrl.push(tgt.value);
       for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
           buttons[i].classList.add('activeMulti');
       }
   }
}
```

I've searched for a while but I couldn't find anything that worked or wasn't JQuery.
The problem is about the part:

```
if (tgt.value === 'Negeren') {
```

Which means if the targeted value = negeren check if it has a certain class. If it has delete that class and if it hasn't add it. This should work like an on and off button, but for some reason it won't add the class and if I delete the else it adds it, but afther it does nothing. Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: Your code attempts to add the `activeMulti` class if it's already there! You need to swap the add and remove lines as the logic is reversed from what you want. Or you can negate the if clause.

Comment: @phuzi Did that tho it still didn't work but I just found out it was because of another very dumb reason. My bad